# How can I insert values into a table, using a subquery with more than one result?

Tags: sql, insert, subquery

I have two tables in SQL Server:

1. article
2. prices

Now I want to select a certain set of ids and insert some entries into the prices-table with those ID.

e.g. (wrong and not working SQL)

```
INSERT INTO prices (group, id, price) 
VALUES (7, (select articleId from article WHERE name LIKE 'ABC%'), 1.50);
```

SQL Error -> subquery has more than 1 value

Comment: Wow! So many correct answers all on Mar 13 '12 at 21:18 (hint: you can hover over the timestamp to get the seconds)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You want:

```
insert into prices (group, id, price)
select 
    7, articleId, 1.50
from article where name like 'ABC%';
```

where you just hardcode the constant fields.

Comment: INSERT INTO `iden_course` (Cse_M_ID,`Cse_M_Name`,`Cse_M_ShName`, `Cse_M_TotSem`,Cse_M_CreatedDate) VALUES ('ID','BJf', 'BJfg' , '4',Now()) select max(Cse_M_ID) as ID from iden_course how to add in this query

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO prices (
    group, 
    id,
    price
) 
SELECT
    7,
    articleId,
    1.50
FROM
    article 
WHERE 
    name LIKE 'ABC%';
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are inserting one record into your table, you can do

```
INSERT INTO yourTable 
VALUES(value1, value2)
```

But since you want to insert more than one record, you can use a `SELECT FROM` in your SQL statement.

so you will want to do this:

```
INSERT INTO prices (group, id, price) 
SELECT 7, articleId, 1.50
from article 
WHERE name LIKE 'ABC%'
```

Answer (score 14):

```
INSERT INTO prices (group, id, price)
  SELECT 7, articleId, 1.50 FROM article WHERE name LIKE 'ABC%'
```

Answer (score 5):

the sub query looks like

```
 insert into table_name (col1,col2,....) values (select col1,col2,... FROM table_2 ...)
```

hope this help

Answer (score 4):

i am using this method.

```
WITH selected AS (
   SELECT articleId FROM article WHERE name LIKE 'ABC%'
) INSERT INTO prices(group, id, price)
  SELECT 7, articleId, 1.50 from selected;
```

Comment: From a performance perspective, this method is much preferred and yielded me a gain of  x27 on PostgreSQL 12, relative to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO prices(group, id, price)
SELECT 7, articleId, 1.50
FROM article where name like 'ABC%';
```