# Insert (multiple) new rows into a table from another table using a subquery?

Tags: mysql

So this is the query I am trying, definately doesnt work.

The subquery returns 3 rows, which I want copied to the new table.

```
INSERT INTO retired
VALUES (SELECT * from questions where status = 'R');
```

I was sure looking at it I was doing it wrong, but here is specifically the question:

Do I need to list all the columns separately, or is there a way to tell it just to move the whole row? The tables attributes and columns are identical.

Comment: Duplicate - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `questions` and `retired` have the same columns (quantity and type), then this should work:

```
INSERT INTO retired
SELECT * from questions where status = 'R';
```

Comment: I see what I did wrong. Thank you. I guess I didnt realize I would not need VALUES to do it this way.