# multiple rows insert in plsql ora 01427

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2tMi.jpg

```
SELECT T.USER_ID
  FROM USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES T
 WHERE T.UOPM_ID = 17
   AND T.PRIV_ID IN (719) ;  67 rows selected

INSERT INTO  USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES (
  ID, PRIV_ID,UOPM_ID,USER_ID,ML_ID,PARENT_ID
) VALUES (
  PRIV_USER_OTH_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
  1792,
  17,
  ( SELECT T.USER_ID
    FROM   USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES T
           JOIN USERS U
           ON U.ID = T.USER_ID
    WHERE  T.UOPM_ID = 17
    AND    T.PRIV_ID IN (719) ),
  NULL,
  1
)
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How to Add "USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES "is the table , 67 rows ?

Comment: do you want to insert 67 rows corresponding to your first query into the user_other_privileges table along with sequence,1792,17 ?

Comment: You post a `select` statement that you say returns 67 rows.  Your `insert` statement contains a similar statement that joins to an additional table `users` but it is not obvious what that join would accomplish.  Either it would do nothing because you aren't referencing `users` in a predicate or in the projection or it would change the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

The error means, that this subquery:

```
SELECT T.USER_ID
    FROM   USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES T
           JOIN USERS U
           ON U.ID = T.USER_ID
    WHERE  T.UOPM_ID = 17
    AND    T.PRIV_ID IN (719)
```

returns more that one row.
Please run this query and you will see that at least 2 user ids will appear.
The INSERT statements with the VALUE clause **can insert only one row** into the table, and it expects only one value for each column in the VALUES clause:

```
INSERT INTO table( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES ( val1, val2, val3 )
```

You can't enter many values to one column in the row.
For example if this subquery returns three numbers: 1,2,3, you cannot insert one row in such a way:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
| ID   | PRIV_ID | UOPM_ID | USER_ID | ML_ID | PARENT_ID | 
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 456  |    1792 |      17 |  1,2,3  |  NULL |         1 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

I guess that you don't want to insert only one row, but you are going to insert one separate row for each entry returned by the suquery, like this:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
| ID   | PRIV_ID | UOPM_ID | USER_ID | ML_ID | PARENT_ID | 
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 456  |    1792 |      17 |      1  |  NULL |         1 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 457  |    1792 |      17 |      2  |  NULL |         1 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 458  |    1792 |      17 |      3  |  NULL |         1 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+
```

In this case you can't use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` syntax, 
you need `INSERT INTO .... subquery` variant instead,
see this answer for more details: [How can I insert values into a table, using a subquery with more than one result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result)


Your insert statement for such a case can be:

```
INSERT INTO  USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES (
  ID, PRIV_ID,UOPM_ID,USER_ID,ML_ID,PARENT_ID
) 
SELECT
     PRIV_USER_OTH_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
     1792,
     17,
     T.USER_ID,
     NULL,
     1
FROM USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES T
JOIN USERS U
ON U.ID = T.USER_ID
WHERE  T.UOPM_ID = 17
  AND  T.PRIV_ID IN (719)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer, thanks :)

```
DECLARE

v_USER_ID INTEGER;


BEGIN
  FOR XYZ IN 
              (
                SELECT T.USER_ID
                FROM   USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES T
                JOIN USERS U
                ON U.ID = T.USER_ID
                WHERE  T.UOPM_ID = 17
                AND    T.PRIV_ID IN (719)
              )
  LOOP
  v_USER_ID:= XYZ.USER_ID;

                INSERT INTO  USER_OTHER_PRIVILEGES
                (ID, PRIV_ID,UOPM_ID,USER_ID,ML_ID,PARENT_ID)
                VALUES
                (PRIV_USER_OTH_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,1792, 17,v_USER_ID, NULL,1);

                COMMIT;

  END LOOP;

END;
```