# How I can copy ID from table A to table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is SQL code:

```
Declare @A_ID  AS A_ID

insert into TBL_FO VALUES(NEWID(), @A_ID, '30000.00','1','1')
(select * from TBL_DETAIL where A_ID = '59366409-2EB6-49BC-A88F-801692B735D6')
```

1. I want to follow or copy the A_ID from TBL_DETAIL  as `'59366409-2EB6-49BC-A88F-801692B735D6'` to TBL_FO for `@A_ID`.. How I can declare the A_ID for copy the same ID

Comment: Can you share please share the structures of `tbl_fo` and `tbl_detail`?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: added `tsql` and `sql-server` tags based on the syntax used

Comment: Noted and thank you guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert values into a table, using a subquery with more than one result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result)

Comment: Tip: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`. A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @A_ID  as varchar(100) -- adjust the length as needed
select @A_ID = A_ID from TBL_DETAIL where A_ID = '59366409-2EB6-49BC-A88F-801692B735D6'

Declare @FO_ID as int -- To insert this into One or more tables
SET @FO_ID = NEWID() -- Initialize it one time.

insert into TBL_FO VALUES(@FO_ID, @A_ID, '30000.00','1','1') -- First use of @FO_ID

insert into TBL_SOMEOTHERTBL VALUES( @FO_ID, .... )  -- Second use of @FO_ID

etc ...
```

Comment: I tried.. thank you for advice. If possible using `INNER JOIN` up to 4 table?

Comment: @KHLIM Iam not sure what you mean by that ... pls elaborate

Comment: this is work from me.. `TBL_FO ` already generate a new ID for FO_ID right. However, can I grab this `FO_ID` for insert another table??

Comment: may I grab the FO_ID in the same to insert another table value?

Comment: Noted and Thank You.

Comment: @KHLIM very vague need more information and I think this will be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns you want to set and then follow with the subquery having the values you need in addition to the A_ID(in the order of your column names) :

```
insert 
into 
   TBL_FO (FirstColumnName, 
           SecondColumnName, 
           ThirdColumnName, 
           FourthColumnName, 
           FifthColumnName) 
(select 
   NEWID(), 
   A_ID, 
   '30000.00', 
   '1', 
   '1' 
 from 
   TBL_DETAIL 
 where 
   A_ID = '59366409-2EB6-49BC-A88F-801692B735D6')
```

Note: there is also the option to not specify the column names if the table columns are in the same order as you insert them

Comment: hello if I answered your question, can you accept my answer please ?

Comment: I think yours is little bit different. I need to change insert into to select

Comment: It is the right way to do it. You don't need to declare a variable for a_id

Comment: this is copy from one all value from table A to table B am I right? i want just only A_ID only.

Comment: no it inserts the right fields... it would copy all value if it was select * but this is not the case