# PHP - Does it need to fetch_array when select then insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I'm writing PHP and mysql. If I want to select then insert to database, I will

- step1.Select from table
- step2. mysqli_fetch_array and contain to variable such as $foo
- step3. INSERT INTO MyTable (firstname)
  VALUES ('$foo')"

Is it possible that I select then insert  without fetch from database?

Comment: If there is no client-side work that needs to be done the "SELECT + INSERT" can be done entirely in SQL, without needing to fetch data back to PHP first. If PHP is required to do work on the data, then it must be fetched back, processed, and then sent onward to the INSERT. The question would benefit from an example case.

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this via mysql you can use

```
INSERT INTO Table2(field1, field2) 
SELECT old_field1 as field1, old_field2 as field2 FROM Table1
```

Just be sure that you match fieldnames with "as".

Answer (score 0):

Its a very simple concept,

> mysqli_fetch_array()

returns an array and you cannot directly store an array into a column of a table in database. Either you have to map with the table column or convert it into json to store it into table column.

Comment: I mean $foo['some column']

Comment: Yes some thing like this