# Copy selected data and increment entry ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have selected my data with;

`SELECT * FROM item_temp WHERE name LIKE '%starter%' AND Inventory LIKE '600';`

I want to duplicate my selected data (Not overwrite it) multiply "entry" of every item in the query by 10.

As an example, the "entry" of one item is: 51327.
I want to make a copy of the item with an entry of 513270.

I have tried a few different methods but they've all resulted in errors and I feel like I'm at a brick wall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: insert into item_temp SELECT entry*10, c2, c3 ... FROM item_temp WHERE name LIKE '%starter%' AND Inventory LIKE '600';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert values into a table, using a subquery with more than one result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result)

Comment: Hi, this didn't help. My struggle is duplicating the selected data and then multiplying the "entry" column by 10. Apologises if I didn't clearly explain well enough. I was also looking to keep all the data in the same table; item_temp

Comment: @CallumKent it's useful to post your attempt and see which error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select (it.entry * 10 + n) as entry, . . .  -- the rest of the columns go here
from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all . . . select 9) n cross join
     item_temp it
where it.name LIKE '%starter%' AND it.Inventory LIKE '600' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INSERT INTO` syntax

```
 INSERT INTO table_name
   <your query with same column order as table_name>;
```

Another option is making the destination table ex-novo with `select ... into` statement

```
SELECT * 
into new_table
FROM item_temp 
WHERE name LIKE '%starter%' 
AND Inventory LIKE '600';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO` with a `SELECT` that does the multiplication you need. You will have to write all columns on for the inserting table.

```
INSERT INTO item_temp (
    entry
    -- , other columns
    )
SELECT
    T.entry * 10 AS entry
    -- , other columns
FROM 
    item_temp T
WHERE 
    name LIKE '%starter%' AND 
    Inventory LIKE '600';
```