# Multiple inserts of multi-valued subqueries

Tags: sql, insert, subquery

I found the single insert answer from this question: [How can I insert values into a table, using a subquery with more than one result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result). However, I'm looking for a way to do multiple inserts in this fashion.

Single-Insert version WORKING! (using the previous answer...):

```
INSERT INTO prices (group, id, price)
SELECT 7, articleId, 1.50 FROM article WHERE name like 'ABC%';
```

Multi-Insert version (**Failing**)

```
INSERT INTO prices (group, id, price)
(select 7, articleId, 1.50 FROM article WHERE name like 'ABC%'),
(select 9, articleId, 2.50 FROM article WHERE name like 'DEF%');
```

Is there a method of doing these multiple inserts of multi-column subqueries with a simple-enough syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`. It does a union of the two result sets while keeping duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO prices
            (group,
             id,
             price)
            SELECT 7,
                   articleId,
                   1.50
                   FROM article
                   WHERE name LIKE 'ABC%'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 9,
                   articleId,
                   2.50
                   FROM article
                   WHERE name LIKE 'DEF%';
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! And since this is mostly test data, I don't have to worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO prices (group, id, price)
select 7, articleId, 1.50 FROM article WHERE name like 'ABC%'
union
select 9, articleId, 2.50 FROM article WHERE name like 'DEF%'
```

You need to have the record inserted coming as one source

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this works! However I don't need to worry about duplicates and it seems like `UNION ALL` executes faster, so I marked the other answer as correct.