# Unable to do batch update with Subquery in Insert or Update in Spring boot NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, named-parameters, namedparameterjdbctemplate

Am trying to insert mutiple records using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchupdate. Am able to insert record without using subquery in Insert statement. But when I use Subquery its returning `dataintegrityviolationexception` Please find below code for your reference,

```
 public void insertBatch(){
       String sql = "insert into emp(id, name, age) values ((select max(id) from company where managerid = :managerid), :name, :age)";
       List<Map<String, Object>> batchVales = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
       batchValues.add(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("name", "example").addValue("age", 30).addValue("managerid", 10).getValues());
       SqlParameterSource[] params = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(batchValues.toArray(new Map[1]));
       jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, params);
    }
```

In above code am using Subquery to fetch max(id) from company table. If I use this subquery its returning error. If I remove and hard code some value its working fine. Why batchupdate not accepting sub query. Am using DB2 Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` form is supported; not the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` form for sub queries.

The pseudo-syntax for INSERT statements is: `INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement.`

Try like this:

```
String sql = "insert into emp(id, name, age) (select max(id) from company where managerid = :managerid), :name, :age";
```

**Updates:**
As pointed out in comment, it should work like this:

```
String sql = "insert into emp(id, name, age) select max(id), :name, :age from company where managerid = :managerid;
```

Extra params which are not part of Select sub query needs to merge in select sub query.

Comment: I tried it. return PrepareStatement call ; bad Sql Grammar exception

Comment: Have you tried by removing brackets of sub query too? or try by just removing `values` from your original query.

Comment: I tried both. Facing same issue. Am using DB2 database

Comment: I tried using Insert into...select. But unable to set multiple values with comma separate. Like Insert into table (id,name,age) select id from company, :name, :age. In this query am unable set value (:name, :age) after select statement.

Comment: I accept this Answer and small modification in your answer : we can't use Insert into...select with multiple named parameter. We can use like below,                        
 String sql = "insert into emp(id, name, age) select max(id), :name, :age from company where managerid = :managerid;. I referred this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result

Comment: Updated your suggestion in answer.