# MySQL for wordpress database; got 10,000 post_IDs from postmeta table, need to insert 10,000 entries back into postmeta table. How?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made many attempts at this problem, using a variety of approaches, and just haven't been able to solve it just yet. Any SQL experts?

This query returns around 10,0000 post_ids:

```sql
SELECT post_id
FROM `Ug77XZe58_postmeta`  
WHERE meta_key LIKE "%_wc_gla_sync_status%";
```

I need to insert back into:

```
`Ug77XZe58_postmeta` (meta_id[AUTOINC], post_id, meta_key, meta_value)

(post_id, '_wc_gla_brand', 'TheYayAtelier')
```

So that every product in the woocommerce database, and their variants, gets assigned the brandname "TheYayAtelier". Google Shopping Listings is complaining about their being no brands on the products.

I've tried

```sql
INSERT INTO `Ug77XZe58_postmeta` (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
    SELECT post_id, '_wc_gla_brand', 'TheYayAtelier'
    FROM `Ug77XZe58_postmeta`
    WHERE post_id IN
(SELECT post_id
FROM `Ug77XZe58_postmeta`  
WHERE meta_key LIKE "%_wc_gla_sync_status%"
);
```

But this makes 290,000 insertions instead of the expected 10,000. Something's wrong.

I then tried

```sql
INSERT INTO `Ug77XZe58_postmeta` (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) 
VALUES(
(SELECT post_id
FROM `Ug77XZe58_postmeta`  
WHERE meta_key LIKE "%_wc_gla_sync_status%"), 
'_wc_gla_brand', 'TheYayAtelier');
```

But this complains about the source and target table being the same. Not sure what I should be doing. Seems straightforward, with 10,000 post_ids, make 10,000 simple insertions using each post_id once, but coming up with the MySQL to do it is proving challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to check for that key? Simple solution would be this:

```
INSERT INTO Ug77XZe58_postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
SELECT Ug77XZe58_posts.id, '_wc_gla_brand', 'TheYayAtelier' FROM Ug77XZe58_posts;
```

This query would add one row for every row in Ug77XZe58_posts, to Ug77XZe58_postmeta. You can see how dynamic values are used, and can change the rest on your own. Since meta_id

Answer (score 0):

[How can I insert values into a table, using a subquery with more than one result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692319/how-can-i-insert-values-into-a-table-using-a-subquery-with-more-than-one-result)

Following the top answer to this question, I came up with:

```sql
insert into `Ug77XZe58_postmeta` (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
select  post_ID, '_wc_gla_brand', 'TheYayAtelier'
from `Ug77XZe58_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_key LIKE "%_wc_gla_sync_status%";
```

And this inserted the expected 10,000 rows. Random product was verified to have the brandname "TheYayAtelier" according to the woocommerce GUI. Appears to work.